# Using patterns inside pgf shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, pgf-core

Is it possible to (correctly) use patterns inside a pgf shape definition ? For example, I try to define a shape as a rectangle filled with a pattern, like this

```
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclareshape{test shape}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}

  \backgroundpath
  {
    \pgfsetfillpattern{north east lines}{.}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
  }
}
```

the problem is that `\pgfsetfillpattern` needs a color argument :

```
\pgfsetfillpattern{pattern name}{pattern color}
```

I want this color to be the color used to draw paths, so I tried to use `.` (the current color in the `xcolor` package). It doesn't work as expected :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=red,test shape] at (0,0) {};
\node[fill=red,test shape] at (2cm,0) {};
\node[color=red,test shape] at (4cm,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces two black shapes and a red one :

[image: two rectangles filled with a black north east lines pattern and then a red one]

I would expect the first one to be red too. So I have two questions

- is it an easy solution to do it ?
- is it a good idea to use patterns inside a pgf shape ? (And if the answer is no, well, why and what to do instead ?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a way to get the stroke colour from PGF itself (`\pgfgetsstrokecolor` isn't a defined macro) but fortunately TikZ stores the colour in its own memory space and so it is possible to use that to get the colour.  There are three such storage places:

```
\tikz@strokecolor
\tikz@fillcolor
tikz@color
.
```

The first two are macros, the last two are colours.  The `draw=colour` option sets the first, the `fill=colour` option sets the second, and the `color=colour` options sets *both* of the last two.

So one solution is to set the colour to be `.` *unless* `\tikz@strokecolor` is set, whereupon we use that.  One way of doing this is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{test shape}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}

  \backgroundpath
  {
    \def\my@color{.}%
    \ifx\tikz@strokecolor\pgfutil@empty
    \else
    \let\my@color\tikz@strokecolor
    \fi
    \pgfsetfillpattern{north east lines}{\my@color}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=red,test shape] at (0,0) {};
\node[fill=red,test shape] at (2cm,0) {};
\node[color=red,test shape] at (4cm,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: coloured patterns]

If you want a different combination then you need to adjust the choices.

Comment: Well, it seems to be the best solution after the nonexistent `\pgfgetsstrokecolor`. Thanks !